# Distinguishing the first run of latex vs. the successive ones, to avoid generating unnecessary missing labels warnings

Tags: labels

Is there a standard way to check whether the current run of latex is the first one or a successive one?

I am writing a package that, as part of its functionality, needs to warn the user if a label is not defined. On the first run, all the labels are undefined, so there are a lot of unnecessary warnings being produced. If I can distinguish between the first run and the successive run, I would be able to silence the unnecessary warnings.

p.s. By the way, I realize that the philosophy is to be "stateless" in regard to the labels - in the usual label/ref functionality the first run generates all the warnings. But IMHO that is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: if you silence all warnings, won't then your users believe that the first run was successfull?

Comment: Well, the usual "undefined references" warnings will still be there and the user/latexmk will run the compilation again.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{not first}{first}
```

Comment: But isn't the aux file being created anyway and therefore always existing? 
Ah, maybe I should use this in the preamble to save the result in a variable...

Comment: @AndreaCensi I was assuming you were using this in your package. The aux is made at `\begin{document}` You would in any case only want to do his once, saving the answer, accessing the filesystem is comparatively slow compared to executing macros.

Comment: what I meant was: save the variable once as opposed to put this as part of the macro expansion. Thanks for clarifying when the aux is created.

Comment: my documents often have older aux-files and the test would fail. hyperref checks if it was loaded in the previous run by writing a command to the aux-file and then checks if it is defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well sure but if it is just a matter of skipping warnings in cases where you know it's a first run, this is safe enough. If you call evry document `blub.tex` so always have an unrelated `blub.aux`  on the first run then you never skip warnings but no harm done.

Comment: I meant that when I load a specific package I often have already compiled the document at least once, e.g. to check the basic setup. In every larger project the "no-aux-file-case" is quite rare. It doesn't harm to test, but I don't see much gain.